# libcheck fails with /usr/bin/ld: cannot find @CHECK_CFLAGS@: No such file or directory

Tags: c, autotools

I'm trying to follow the check tutorial [here](https://libcheck.github.io/check/doc/check_html/check_3.html#How-to-Write-a-Test) to try and setup a test suite. My project structure is like

```
root
  |-----src
         |----- foo.h, foo.c
        test
         |----- root_test.h, root_test.c, foo_test.c
        Makefile.am
        configure.ac
```

My foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

int func();

#endif
```

foo.c:

```
#include "foo.h"

int func() { return 0; }
```

root_test.h:

```
#ifndef ROOT_TEST_H
#define ROOT_TEST_H

#include <check.h>

Suite *foo_suite();

#endif
```

root_test.c:

```
#include <check.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "root_test.h"

int main() {
  int fc;
  SRunner *sr;

  sr = srunner_create(foo_suite());

  srunner_run_all(sr, CK_NORMAL);
  fc = srunner_ntests_failed(sr);
  srunner_free(sr);

  return fc == 0 ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

foo_test.c:

```
#include <check.h>

#include "../src/foo.h"
#include "root_test.h"

START_TEST(foo_func) { ck_assert_int_eq(func(), 0); }
END_TEST

Suite *foo_suite() {
  Suite *s;
  TCase *tc;

  s = suite_create("Foo");
  tc = tcase_create("Core");

  tcase_add_test(tc, foo_func);

  suite_add_tcase(s, tc);
  return s;
}
```

My Makefile.am:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libroot.la

HFILES =\
  src/foo.h       

CFILES =\
  src/foo.c

libroot_la_SOURCES = $(HFILES) $(CFILES)

TESTS = libroot_test
check_PROGRAMS = libroot_test
libroot_test_SOURCES = $(HFILES) test/root_test.h test/root_test.c test/foo_test.c
libroot_test_CFLAGS = @CHECK_CFLAGS@
libroot_test_LDADD = libroot.la @CHECK_LIBS@

noinst_PROGRAMS = libroot_test
```

and my configure.ac:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.71])
AC_INIT([libroot], [0.0.1], [swdon@users.noreply.github.com])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/foo.h])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign subdir-objects])
AM_PROG_AR

LT_INIT

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CC

# Checks for libraries.

# Checks for header files.

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T

# Checks for library functions.
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_FUNC_REALLOC

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

My `autoreconf -i` and `./configure` run without any issues. When I run `make check` I get the following output with error:

```
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc @CHECK_CFLAGS@ -g -O2   -o libroot_test  test/libroot_test-libroot_test.o test/libroot_test-foo_test.o libroot.la @CHECK_LIBS@ 
libtool: link: gcc @CHECK_CFLAGS@ -g -O2 -o .libs/libroot_test test/libroot_test-libroot_test.o test/libroot_test-foo_test.o @CHECK_LIBS@  ./.libs/libroot.so -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find @CHECK_CFLAGS@: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find @CHECK_LIBS@: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:687: libroot_test] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@CHECK_CFLAGS@` and `@CHECK_LIBS@` strings appearing in your `Makefile.am` are placeholders for the values of Autoconf output variables, but your original `configure.ac` does not contain anything that would set such output variables.  As a result, the placeholders are carried through unchanged to generated makefiles, where they cause builds to fail with the observed error.

The Check documentation contains [a section about integrating libcheck with Autotools-based build systems](http://check.sourceforge.net/doc/check_html/check_5.html).  Its recommendation is to use the the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` provided by pkg-config.  For example,

```
# ...

# Checks for libraries.
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([CHECK], [check >= 0.9.6])

# ...
```

The second macro parameter specifies the minimum acceptable version of Check, and it may be omitted if you do not wish to specify a minimum version.

Note also that older versions of `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` do not automatically make the relevant variables Autoconf output variables.  If you were saddled with such a version and were unable to update, then you would also want to add

```
AC_SUBST([CHECK_CFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([CHECK_LIBS])
```

after `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`.

If you do not have pkg-config or do not want your package build to rely on it then there is also an `AM_PATH_CHECK()` macro provided by Check itself that can serve the purpose.  That macro is deprecated, however, and therefore may be removed from some future version of Check.  Refer to the documentation for more information on this macro.

Comment: And as always, when you use macros from outside of the set which Autoconf (AC_*) and Automake (AM_*) come with, it is useful to have `m4_pattern_forbid([^PKG_CHECK_MODULES])` somewhere before `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`: That will properly catch the case when there is no `pkg.m4` installed at `autoreconf` time.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I added the `AM_PATH_CHECK` to my configure.ac and it's working now. My updated configure.ac:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.71])
AC_INIT([libccg],[0.0.1],[smadurange@users.noreply.github.com])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/foo.h])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign subdir-objects])
AM_PROG_AR
AM_PATH_CHECK

LT_INIT

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CC

# Checks for libraries.

# Checks for header files.

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T

# Checks for library functions.
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_FUNC_REALLOC

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Comment: [The documentation](http://check.sourceforge.net/doc/check_html/check_5.html) recommends using `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` for this purpose, and notes that the `AM_PATH_CHECK` macro is deprecated. See also [the Autotools Mythbuster commentary about `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`](https://autotools.info/pkgconfig/pkg_check_modules.html) for additional details, especially if you use an older version of that macro.

Comment: @JohnBollinger indeed yours is the correct answer. Thanks for pointing it out. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Ok, done, @kovac.